# LIKE query is unable to retrieve data, why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This query is unable to retrieve any data from MySQL for reasons I cannot figure out after countless hours..

```
public function search()
{
  if(isset($_GET['search']))
  {
    $searchTerms = trim(strip_tags($_GET['search']));

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles WHERE (article_content LIKE :search) OR (article_title LIKE :search)");
    $sth->execute( array(':search' => '%' . $searchTerms . '%') );

    if($sth->fetchColumn() > 0)
    {
      while($row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
        return "search results: " . $row['article_title'];
        return "" . $row['article_content'];
      }
    } else {
      echo "No results.";
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what keyword I type in the form it always returns "No results.". What could be the issue because from what I can see it should work..

Selecting all rows from the table structure and counting so that `fetchColumn` can be runned, it is selecting from the correct table (`articles`), where `article_content` and `article_title` are both rows in the table, so what is the issue?

Comment: Append '%' in search content and try again

Comment: Have you tryed to echo your command and then rum the row sql statement and see the output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth->execute(array(':search' => '%'.$searchTerms.'%'));
```

Should be:

```
$sth->execute(array(':search' => '\'%\' + \''.$searchTerms.'\' + \'%\''));
```

Comment: The same thing as before.

Answer (score 0):

Each bind var needs to be an individual bind var, even when named, and even when they both contain the same value:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM articles 
      WHERE (article_content LIKE :search1) 
         OR (article_title LIKE :search2)"
);
$sth->execute( 
    array(
        ':search1' => '%' . $searchTerms . '%', 
        ':search2' => '%' . $searchTerms . '%'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Honestly I don't know what else it is, I've checked everything and yet gives "No results". It is definitely connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles WHERE (article_content LIKE :search0) OR (article_title LIKE :search1)");

$searchstring="%" . $searchTerms . "%";

$sth->execute( array(':search0' =>$searchstring ,':search1'=>$searchstring) );

pdo fails to retrieve values when the same placheholder is repeated in a query with LIKE in it.
```